# Matlab integral over function of symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, integral

In an attempt to speed up `for` loops (or eliminate all together), I've been trying to pass matrices into functions.  I have to use sine and cosine as well.  However, when I attempt to find the integral of a matrix where the elements are composed of sines and cosines, it doesn't work and I can't seem to find a way to make it do so.

I have a matrix `SI` that is composed of sines and cosines with respect to a variable that I have defined using the Symbolic Math Toolbox.  As such, it would actually be even better if I could just pass the `SI` matrix and receive a matrix of values that is the integral of the sine/cosine function at every location in this matrix.  I would essentially get a square matrix back.  I am not sure if I phrased that very well, but I have the following code below that I have started with.

```
I = [1 2; 3 4];
J = [5 6; 7 8];
syms o;
j = o*J;
SI = sin(I + j);
%SI(1,1) = sin(5*o + 1)
integral(@(o) o.*SI(1,1), 0,1);
```

Ideally, I would want to solve `integral(@(o) o*SI,0,1)` and get a matrix of values.  What should I do here?

Comment: Honestly, I have no real idea what your code is intended to do. Are you trying to define a function SI(o)=... and get the integral of SI from 0 to 1? If you try to speed up code, using symbolic math is typically not a good idea.

Comment: The alternative in my actual code is several nested for loops, is there an alternative to symbolic math I'm not aware of? What I need is 

    integral(@(o) o.*sin((square matrix) + o*(square matrix) + square matrix), -1/2, 1/2)

What I'm currently doing is running two nested for loops to iterate over every element in the square matrices. I need to do this for 8 integrals, which is taking much longer than is practical

Comment: Please describe it in words / on a mathematical level. Not working code does not tell me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 3 square NxN matrices, A, B, C. I need to integrate over a length, which provides my limits. The integral is integral(o*sin(A + o*B + C)do). I wish to apply this function so that I get an NxN matrix back. Currently I am using two for loops to iterate over every element and it is very slow. Sorry, I seem to struggle to put this into words adequately.

Comment: @Kyle - That explanation helped.  I have provided an answer for you.  Good luck.

Comment: @Daniel - I have edited the question to make it more clear based on the OP's comments.  I believe I have adequately answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `A`, `B` and `C` are all `N x N` matrices, for the moment, let's assume they're all `2 x 2` matrices to make the example I'm illustrating more succinct to understand.  Let's also define `o` as a mathematical symbol based on your comments in your question above.

```
syms o;
A = [1 2; 3 4];
B = [5 6; 7 8];
C = [9 10; 11 12];
```

Let's also define your function `f` according to your comments:

```
f = o*sin(A + o*B + C)
```

We thus get:

```
f =

[ o*sin(5*o + 10), o*sin(6*o + 12)]
[ o*sin(7*o + 14), o*sin(8*o + 16)]
```

Remember, for each element in `f`, we take the corresponding elements in `A`, `B` and `C` and add them together.  As such, for the first row and first column of each matrix, we have `1, 5` and `9`.  As such, `A + o*B + C` for the first row, first column equates to: `1 + 5*o + 9 = 5*o + 10`.

Now if you want to integrate, just use the `int` command.  This will find the **exact** integral, provided that the integral can be solvable in closed form.  `int` also can handle matrices so it will integrate each element in the matrix.  You can call it like so:

```
out = int(f,a,b);
```

This will integrate `f` for each element from the lower bound `a` to the upper bound `b`.  As such, supposing our limits were from `0` to `1` as you said.  Therefore:

```
out = int(f,0,1);
```

We thus get:

```
out =

[ sin(15)/25 - sin(10)/25 - cos(15)/5, sin(18)/36 - sin(12)/36 - cos(18)/6]
[ sin(21)/49 - sin(14)/49 - cos(21)/7, sin(24)/64 - sin(16)/64 - cos(24)/8]
```

Bear in mind that `out` is defined in the symbolic math toolbox.  If you want the **actual numerical values**, you need to cast the answer to `double`.  Therefore:

```
finalOut = double(out);
```

We thus get:

```
finalOut =

0.1997   -0.1160
0.0751   -0.0627
```

Obviously, this can generalize for any size `M x N` matrices, so long as they **all** share the same dimensions.

### Caveat

`sin`, `cos`, `tan` and the other related functions have their units in **radians**.  If you wish for the **degrees** equivalent, append a `d` at the end of the function (i.e. `sind`, `cosd`, `tand`, etc.)

---

I believe this is the answer you're after.  Good luck!

Comment: @Kyle - Do you require any more assistance?